# How to add values to list?

Tags: c#

I try add values to list when List<> is null.

But have error: `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`
How to resolve this?

Here my code:

```
List<DTOSaveFromFile> lst = DiskFile.Load();
if (lst.Count.Equals(0))
{
    lst[0].reportName = item["report"].ToString();
    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;
    string sTime = nowTime.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    lst[0].time = sTime;
    DiskFile.Save(lst);
}
```

Class DiskFile:

```
public static void Save(List<DTOSaveFromFile> Items)
{
    //File.WriteAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()).ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
    File.AppendAllLines(dataPath, (from i in Items select i.Serialize()).ToArray(), Encoding.Default);
}



public static List<DTOSaveFromFile> Load()
{
    string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(dataPath);
    return (from i in data select new DTOSaveFromFile(i)).ToList<DTOSaveFromFile>();
}
```

Edited:
This show error like:
`'Email.DTOSaveFromFile' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments`. I think it's missing arguments and try add parameter but not also happen error.
I was try :

```
lst.Add(new DTOSaveFromFile(string report, string email, string time)
{
      reportName = item["tenbaocao"].ToString()
      time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
});
```

Here my code of DTOSaveFromFile.cs:

```
public class DTOSaveFromFile
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }

    public DTOSaveFromFile(string _reportname, string _email, string _time)
    {
        reportName = _reportname;
        eMail = _email;
        time = _time;
    }

    public DTOSaveFromFile(string str)
    {
        reportName = "";
        eMail = "";
        time = "";

        try
        {
            string[] parts = str.TrimEnd().Split('\t');

            reportName = parts[0];
            eMail = parts[1];
            time = parts[2];
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Before you ask a question in this forum, please consider to google your problem and also lookup MSDN (Microsoft Dveloper Network).

Comment: I checked MSDN. I saw like @kienct89 reply. But I don't know pass error. So, I post a new question. I understand my question is resolve in many questions in Stackoverflow. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're checking if the list is empty, then set value for the first item in the list, which is wrong.

You need to add new item to the list instead;

```
List<DTOSaveFromFile> lst = DiskFile.Load();
if (lst.Count == 0)
{
    lst.Add(new DTOSaveFromFile {
        reportName = item["report"].ToString(),
        time = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
    });
}
DiskFile.Save(lst);
```

**UPDATE (based on op's edit):**
Since you don't have empty constructor, you can use parameter constructor

```
List<DTOSaveFromFile> lst = DiskFile.Load();
if (lst.Count == 0)
{
    lst.Add(new DTOSaveFromFile(item["report"].ToString(), "", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")));
}
DiskFile.Save(lst);
```